# GridViewRowCommand keep fire

Tags: c#, asp.net

by right my label1.text will be display by each clicks, however my label was fire during page load, and this is not what i want, so any idea can perform fire event per clicks?

**gridview property**

asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnRowDataBound="abcde"

**link button that inside gridview**

asp:LinkButton ID="lnkname" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("movieTitle") %>' Width=500 CommandName="cmdLink">

**code behind for link button**

protected void abcde(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)

```
{

    Label1.Text = ((LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("lnkname")).Text;


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that whenever any click event occur in Gridview that time GridviewRowCommand will be fire..you just check that when you want to fire this event.its means during paging event also fire this event..thats y just check it out using [CommandName] like this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx

```
        string namec = e.CommandName.ToString();
        if (namec == "cmdLink")
        {
           //put your code  
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you bind the gridview on page load event. Every time you bind the gridview, the onbound event will be fired:

> protected void abcde(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)

You can avoid that by checking postback in pageload before gridview databind:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
     //Gridview databind
}
```

Comment: i put GridView1.DataBind() under isPostBack the result still the same=(

Comment: Your code in GridViewRowBound --> abcde will execute as many times as your gridview has rows. In what condition do you want to initialize Label1.Text to the linkbutton text? Right now your code initialize for all the linkbuttons in all gridview rows.

Comment: that just an example, what i want to do is different link button have different link to different page~

Answer (score 0):

Change the Command Name of LinkButton to

```
CommandName="Select"
```

and use `GridView1_SelectIndexChanged` event 
First Get the Select Row

```
GridViewRow gvr =  new  GridView1.SelectedRow;
```

and `FindControl` of the row